# Can I use our company's Azure AD as user store when creating a Visual Studio Team System account?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

According to this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-aad?view=vsts) I can connect VSTS to the company's Azure AD.

We are creating a new VSTS instance, is it then possible to connect it to our Azure AD right from the start? I am only a normal user in our Azure AD.

Comment: If I recall correctly you can create the VSTS tenant from the Azure portal and connect it to the same AAD currently selected in the portal. See “Connect your VSTS organization” in the link you mentioned, where it’s done retroactively. Off course, this only works if you have sufficient rights in both VSTS and in Azure

Comment: We are a global company and I want to connect VSTS to our global Azure AD, but the billing for this VSTS instance (which is for a specific business unit) should not be billed to the Azure account holding our Azure AD but an Azure subscription belonging to our business unit. I have opened a ticket to Microsoft for this but even they seem to be struggling with it.